# Double acronym/initialism: acronyms and initialisms that stand for two things simultaneously

Tags: single-word-requests, acronyms, initialisms

I am looking for a term that describes an acronym that has two possible expansions, but both expansions refer to the same thing. The term "double acronym" doesn't appear to be widely used and is confusing. Some examples:

In human-computer interaction, there is a single tool called [CPM-GOMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPM-GOMS), where the CPM stands for both "cognitive, perceptual, motor" and "critical path method".

Additionally, a popular cognitive modeling tool called [ACT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACT-R) has both "Atomic Components of Thought" and "Adaptive Character of Thought" as its meanings.

In both cases, these are not two distinct tools that coincidentally share the same acronym. They are acronyms that purposefully have two distinct expansions that refer to the same tool.

The usage might also apply to companies who have changed the words in their acronym while keeping the original initialism, such as:

- Marvel's [SHIELD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.H.I.E.L.D.)
- the programming language [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php)
- the chain store [TCBY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCBY)
- the college exam [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT)

However in these cases one expansion is clearly non-standard. There are also unofficial acronyms, such as [DVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD), which appears to be used equally as "digital video disc" and "digital versatile disc", despite that neither is standard.

It may also apply to translations in which the initialism is preserved, such as the car company [BMW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bmw) which stands for Bayerische Motoren Werke AG, but is often written as Bavarian Motor Works.

There is no wikipedia for "double acronym" and < 6,500 google results for the same search term. Is there a standard term for this usage that I am not aware of? If not, what short phrasing could be best used to describe this usage? Note I am primarily interested in a phrase that captures the first usage (e.g. CPM and ACT).

Comment: "ambiguous" doesn't work for you?

Comment: @Mitch no, i wouldn't say the acronym is ambiguous. it definitively has two expansions that refer to the same thing.

Comment: "double acronym" doesn't lead one to think of what you are asking about. You're saying two identical acronyms (same letter sequence), that are abbreviations of two different sets of words, but in the end they still refer to the same thing? I don't think there's a single word for such a thing. It's hard enough to explain. Sure it happens, but a few words is not a problem.

Comment: ambiguous means ["open to more than one interpretation"](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambiguous?q=ambiguous).

Comment: @Mitch yes, that is exactly what i'm referring to. in fact, i'm currently writing a review that uses both of the examples i mentioned--hence my predicament. most authors simply ignore one of the possible expansions, but i feel that is misleading.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean -- to a doctor, LOL might mean Little Old Lady, not Laughing Out Loud. The same acronym refers to two separate ideas. I get the sense that you are looking for an acronym which refers to 2 different sets of words but somehow that 2 sets of words still point to some identical idea?

Comment: @Dan yes. i would call the LOL example an ambiguous acronym, but that is not what i am looking for. your latter statement is correct. i think the intent is to express multiple aspects of the referent.

Comment: and may I assume that you aren't looking for something like SAT = Scholastic Aptitude Test and Standardized Achievement Test because they are different but related understandings of the single acronym, not completely separate sets of words which, coincidentally, point to the same idea.

Comment: @Dan I'm not sure--if by standardized achievement test you mean *any* standardized test, like the ACT, I would say no. but i have never heard of SAT being used for anything other than [a specific, proprietary test called the SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT). However, the wikipedia notes that SAT--now an empty acronym--has once meant "Scholastic Aptitude Test" and then "Scholastic Assessment Test", both of which refer to the same thing. So that would count, though both are now non-standard.

Comment: I misremembered the other SAT meaning but that is my point -- people see the letters as referring to 2 separate sets of words but the words are related (the same holds for the P in PSAT which some say is for Practice, and others say Preliminary). So you don't need completely distinct sets of words.

Comment: yes, it's fine if the words are related-- the important point is that the words are different, but they refer to the exact same entity

Comment: Do you mean like when I read this and said to myself, WTF? (*what the frag*) ;-)

Comment: A nice way to tear one's hair: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297961/what-does-gnu-means

Comment: cf. my somewhat-related question: "[Term for when acronyms are the same in more than one language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/28672/12995)"

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen often enough for there to be a single word, or even a standard phrase.

However, as Mitch suggested, *[ambiguous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ambiguous?q=ambiguous)* means:

> open to more than one interpretation; not
>    having one obvious meaning

Therefore *ambiguous acronym* is a good match.

However, remember an *acronym* is usually an initialism or abbreviation pronounced as a word, like NASA, radar, laser and ACT, unlike BBC and CPM.

So *ambiguous abbreviation* is a more general term.

Comment: I'm not looking for a single word necessarily, that tag was added by someone else. Ambiguous is a good suggestion, but to me that connotes, e.g., an acronym used by two organizations for different purposes. thanks for the 'abbreviation' tip

Comment: Yes, ambiguous could also mean the same abbreviation is used for two or more different things (eg HMI for Her Majesty's Inspector, Heavy Metal Ions, Himalayan Mountaineering Institute and Hrvatske Matice Iseljenika), but, well, ambiguous is ambiguous like that! You may have to be more explicit, and perhaps introduce any term the first time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I came here looking for the same thing.

The best I've come up with is 'dual acronym'.

dual: consisting of two parts, elements, or aspects.
The two aspects here being the two expansions that have the same underlying meaning.

'Double acronym' seems to connote two expansions that have different meanings, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

Is [Equivocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation) ("to call by the same name") closer to your intention? I'd agree that *ambiguous* perhaps doesn't have the correct connotation of "intentionality" that you are after.